# merging two files according to the specified row

Tags: text-processing, awk, sed

I have **file1.txt** looks as follows:

```
search
http://google.com
mail
https://gmail.com
```

**file2.txt** looks like this:

```
This is a search tool
This is your mail account
```

I need to merge them in the way that **file1.txt** will looks like this:

```
This is a search tool
http://google.com
This is your mail account
https://gmail.com
```

Comment: hint: use GNU sed's relative addressing and `R` command

Comment: Welcome , You can [edit your question here](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464777/edit)

Comment: after your last edit I am getting syntax error

Comment: off course I am changing file1 and file2, here is the isuue

Comment: awkNR: cmd. line:1: Possible syntax error

Comment: please [**Click Here**](https://unix.stackexchange.com/posts/464777/edit) and add the command into your question how you are running and post the error you are getting.

Answer (score 1):

Try also

```
awk '
NR == FNR   {T[$0]
             next
            }
            {for (t in T) if (t ~ $1) $1 = t
            }
1
' file2 file1
This is a search tool
http://google.com
This is your mail account
https://gmail.com
```

Comment: since you are holding the file2 into the array, it will print both `search` and `http://google.com` if no line `This is a search tool` found in file2 previously.

Comment: @αғsнιη: Which is not excluded by the specification. Should the requestor change his/her mind, that can be easily "repaired".

Answer (score 0):

Using `awk`:

```
awk 'NR==FNR{ (NR%2? keyword=$0: seen[keyword]=$0 ); next}  
     { for (keys in seen)if ($0 ~ keys) {print $0, seen[keys] }
}' OFS='\n' file1  file2
```

Output is:

```
This is a search tool
http://google.com
This is your mail account
https://gmail.com
```

**explanation:**

if it's first file `NR==FNR` and record/line number is even `NR%2` hold the entire `$0` line into the variable called `keyword` else add that line into an associated array named `seen` with keyword found as it's index, then read the `next` line.

... once first file proceed, with `for-loop` we are traversing the array *seen* and `keys` variable used to point to this array's indexes' elements and checking if that `keys` can match in lines in `file2` then `print $0` that tine followed by its keys' value by `seen[keys]` separated with a `\n`ewline.

Comment: Thnks, but it is not working when applicable to "real" file. Please note that keyfile (search, mail) is in the middle of string and foles has around 100 rows in "real".
Could you please explain the script in detail ? I will try to edit it. Thnks

Comment: @Martin please edit your question and show us an example that accurately reflects your actual file. This answer assumes the search pattern will be the entire line and the only thing on the line. This is what your example shows. If that's not the case, please clarify.

Comment: the search patter should be just a word, as in example: search or mail